# Error while saving launch configuration in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse-plugin

I have some JUnit files that I need to find coverage.

I installed the EclEmma plugin and I chose the Coverage configurations.

Then in the *"Class Path"* I selected the *'User Entries'* and then selected the "*Add folder"* radio button, then I selected the source of my project and pressed 'Apply' button.

The Eclipse shows an error message like this:

> ***exception occurred while saving launch configuration - Permission Denied
>   Reason :- Couldn't write launch configurations.***

Anyone came across the error before?

Currently I'm launching the project from my current user account in CentOS-6.

*Which file I need to update to avoid Permission Denied Error?*

Comment: As some workspace files are not owned by my current user because I used eclipse from my root user before. So I changed the workspace files ownership to my current user and now I can able to save the launch configurations. I used > chown -R username:username <path-to-workspace>. Now there is no error and everything is fine.